# MS Project server 2016 update custom fields on tasks

Tags: rest, soap, ms-project

For Project Server 2013 we’ve been using the SOAP API’s QueueUpdateProjectRequest to achieve this but in 2016 we can’t even checkout the project using SOAP.

We try to POST to /PWA/_vti_bin/psi/Project.asmx:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?><ns2:Envelope xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/project/server/webservices/Project/" xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><ns2:Header></ns2:Header><ns2:Body><ns3:CheckOutProject><ns3:projectUid>7475f3ef-226e-e611-80d3-0050568a983b</ns3:projectUid><ns3:sessionUid>c430ce2b-057e-4990-b5b6-9c6f28415739</ns3:sessionUid><ns3:sessionDescription></ns3:sessionDescription></ns3:CheckOutProject></ns2:Body></ns2:Envelope>
```

and get:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><s:Fault><faultcode xmlns:a="http://Microsoft.Office.Project.Server">a:ProjectServerFaultCode</faultcode><faultstring>Unhandled Communication Fault occurred</faultstring><detail><string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">Incorrect inproc routing.  No inproc host is available for Project.</string></detail></s:Fault></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

We’ve also tried writing the custom field values using custom field internal names when Merge Posting to /ProjectServer/Projects('{#project}')/Draft/Tasks('{#Id}’.
The server seems to ignore the custom field values while correctly updating system field values.

There is documentation for updating custom fields on Project, but not on Task: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Project-REST-Basic-Operations/blob/master/updateprojectcustomfieldvalues.ps1

What is the proper way for updating custom fields on Tasks in Project Server 2016?

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft, there is no Project class in the PSI anymore:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt422816(v=office.16).aspx#Anchor_2

> **Project Server Interface (PSI) Project class removed**
>   The Project class in the PSI is not supported in Project Server 2016. For all new development, use the Project Client Side Object Model (CSOM).

I'm getting the same error for calling PSI functions from the Project class.
I'm not 100% sure, but I guess on the server itself, the REST/SOAP operations are still using the PSI in the end, so you get the same error.

No idea whether you can still achieve what you need with the REST/SOAP.
The solution will be to use CSOM (as suggested by Microsoft), but I don't know if it fits your application.